# merging recurrent layers with dense layer in Keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, theano, keras

I want to build a neural network where the two first layers are feedforward and the last one is recurrent.
here is my code :

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(150, input_dim=23,init='normal',activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(80,activation='relu',init='normal'))
model.add(SimpleRNN(2,init='normal')) 
adam =OP.Adam(lr=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-08)
model.compile(loss="mean_squared_error", optimizer="rmsprop")
```

and I get this error :

```
Exception: Input 0 is incompatible with layer simplernn_11: expected  ndim=3, found ndim=2.
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=adam)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is correct that in Keras, RNN layer expects input as `(nb_samples, time_steps, input_dim)`. However, if you want to add RNN layer after a Dense layer, you still can do that after reshaping the input for the RNN layer. Reshape can be used both as a first layer and also as an intermediate layer in a sequential model. Examples are given below:

**Reshape as first layer in a Sequential model**

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Reshape((3, 4), input_shape=(12,)))
# now: model.output_shape == (None, 3, 4)
# note: `None` is the batch dimension
```

**Reshape as an intermediate layer in a Sequential model**

```
model.add(Reshape((6, 2)))
# now: model.output_shape == (None, 6, 2)
```

For example, if you change your code in the following way, then there will be no error. I have checked it and the model compiled without any error reported. You can change the dimension as per your need.

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, SimpleRNN, Reshape
from keras.optimizers import Adam

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(150, input_dim=23,init='normal',activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(80,activation='relu',init='normal'))
model.add(Reshape((1, 80)))
model.add(SimpleRNN(2,init='normal')) 
adam = Adam(lr=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-08)
model.compile(loss="mean_squared_error", optimizer="rmsprop")
```

Answer (score 3):

In Keras, you cannot put a Reccurrent layer after a Dense layer because the Dense layer gives output as (nb_samples, output_dim). However, a Recurrent layer expects input as (nb_samples, time_steps, input_dim). So, a Dense layer gives a 2-D output, but a Recurrent layer expects a 3-D input. However, you can do the reverse, i.e., put a Dense layer after a Recurrent layer.

Comment: thank you for your response, in fact  the inputs that i use here are correlated ,so i want to create  a short  memory in the last layer that means the output of the system at time t has to take into account the output at time t-1 and , (therefore i want the last layer to be recurrent preceded two forward layers ) do you know how can i make the number of sequences (time_steps) variable ?